# Goalng exec.Command with exiftool creates extra file named {filename}_original when setting tags

Tags: go, exiftool

I'm attempting to update image metadata using golang. The simplest way I've found to do this is simply running exiftool with os/exec, but for some reason this also creates a file that contains the original tags, called whatever the original file is called, plus "_original".

Simplified code is as follows:

```golang
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("exiftool", "-ImageDescription=\"this should work???\"", "image.png")
    err := cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

It *does* set the tags as expected, but creates an extra file called "image.png_original". As far as I can tell this has no reason to happen. I've checked documentation for os/exec as well as exiftool and haven't found anything.

While I could just delete the extra file, that's messy and I'm sure there's a better way that I just haven't been able to figure out.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

As [the exiftool documentation](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Tag-operations) says, you can use the option  `"-delete_original"` . You can consider `"-overwrite_original"` option as well, depending on your exact use case. You can read [the docs](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#Tag-operations) for more information

Comment: Direct link to the [`-overwrite_original` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original).  This is most likely the option you want to use.  There is also the [`-overwrite_original_in_place` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original_in_place), but that is slower and you usually only want to use that in cases where there is other filesystem data attached to the file, such as `XAttr`/`MDItem` on Mac or ADS on Windows.